# Changing object variables to abbreviations before passing it to a network graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array with nodes and edges and I would like to change the name of each company to abbreviation so for example Anglo American would be AA and delete from those strings plc is it possible without copying this object to a different 'var' and then modyfing the data and passing to d3.layout?

```
array (size=2)
  'nodes' => 
    array (size=33)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'Anglo American plc' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'Associated British Foods plc' (length=28)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'Admiral Group plc' (length=17)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'ARM Holdings plc' (length=16)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'Aviva plc' (length=9)
      5 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'BAE Systems plc' (length=15)
      6 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'Barclays PLC' (length=12)
```

and below are edges in this same object.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
                                 .nodes(dataset.nodes)
                                 .links(dataset.edges)
                                 .size([w, h])
                                 .linkDistance([50])
                                 .charge([-200])
                                 .start();
```

Comment: You want to just change name to abbreviation?

Comment: yes so it would be displayed as an abbreviation and on hover I would make it display the full name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to comments under the question maybe this would be the simplest solution `(as line of code)`:

```js
var data = [{
  'name': 'Anglo American plc'
}, {
  'name': 'Associated British Foods plc'
}, {
  'name': 'Admiral Group plc'
}, {
  'name': 'ARM Holdings plc'
}, {
  'name': 'Aviva plc'
}, {
  'name': 'BAE Systems plc'
}, {
  'name': 'Barclays PLC'
}];

data.forEach(d => {d.name = d.name.split(' ').map(w => w[0]).join('')});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: One problem that I encounter is that I would like to have abbreviations in a different variable and not change the original object.

Comment: @Higeath Then you have to change `d.name = ...` to something like `d.addr = ...`; and if you want to get rid of name property you can delete it after setting of `abbr` by just calling `delete d.name`.

Comment: one more thing could you tell me how I could get rid of last word from that before I make abbreviation I would want to get rid of PLC plc from those words.[/b]

Comment: If it's always _plc_ you can add a condition on `map` call to check if it's _plc_ then instead of `w[0]` return `""` (empty string). in addition you can convert value `toLowerCase` in order to check against other cases of _plc_ (like _PLC_)